# How to mock the class of an Rspec Verifying double

Tags: rspec, rspec3

If I'm using a Verifying Double (`object_double`), how do I mock the class of an object so that `===` works?

E.g, if my code looks like this:

```
def foo(record)
  case record
  when Bar
    OtherObject.call
  end
end
```

This doesn't work:

```
it 'should call OtherObject if record is instance of Bar'
  record = object_double(Bar.new, class: Bar)
  expect(OtherObject).to receive(:call)
  foo(record)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're mocking the `class` method of your `record` object, the code under test is using the `case` operator, which relies on the `===` method of `Bar`. The `===` operator is described informally in terms of whether the argument is a "kind of" the given class, but there are no guarantees that the implementation will use the `kind_of?` or `is_a?` or `class` or any other particular method. CRuby 2.1.5 in particular, is implemented as follows:

```
               static VALUE
rb_mod_eqq(VALUE mod, VALUE arg)
{
    return rb_obj_is_kind_of(arg, mod);
}
```

As such, I think the only way you can be assured that the code under test will work is to mock the `===` operator of `Bar` as follows:

```
describe 'stack overflow question' do
  it 'should call OtherObject if record is instance of Bar' do
    record = double
    allow(Bar).to receive(:===).with(record).and_return(true)
    expect(OtherObject).to receive(:call)
    foo(record)
  end
end
```